# What will be it's graph?

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

What will be the graph of
$y=2x +\sin x $
and
$y=x \sin x$
and what's the method to graph functions of this type.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B2x+%2B+sin+x%2C+x+sin+x%7D. You would create a table of values for example, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%5B2x+%2B+sin+x%2C%7Bx%2C+-2+pi%2C+2+pi%2C+.25%7D%5D

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the first function $f(x)=2x+\sin(x)$. We can see that:

- $D_f=\mathbb R$.
- The function is differentiable in $\mathbb R$.
- $f'(x)=2+\cos(x)$. Since $|\cos(x)|\leq1$ so $f'(x)\subseteq [+1,+3]$ so for all $x\in D_f$, $f'>0$ so $f(x)$ is always increasing.

By a nice table of $x$ and their $y$'s we have the following plot. I made it using Maple.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a value table to draw the graph.

Neither do the given graphs have a special name, nor is there a special method to draw the graphs.